# Inserting a RenderPage into a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a div that has a RenderPage in it when a link is clicked using JQuery, without much success.

I tried both ways in the sample and a few more.

```
<div id="fleet-menu">
  <span>
    <a href="#" id="fleet-cartypes">Car Types</a>
  </span>
</div>

<script>
  $("#fleet-cartypes").click(function () {
    $('<div> @RenderPage("CarTypes.cshtml") </div>').insertAfter("#fleet-menu");
  });
        ___________________________________________________________________

  $("#fleet-cartypes").click(function () {
    $("<div id='fleet-main'></div>").insertAfter("#fleet-menu");
    $("#fleet-main").load("@RenderPage("CarTypes.cshtml")");
  });
</script>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you try? `load({@RenderPage("CarTypes.cshtml")})`

Comment: I tried it now, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `appendTo()` and `prependTo()` functions. They're made for that task as `append()` and `prepend()`. Also you can combine all calls to save lines of code and extra variables:

```
$("#fleet-cartypes").click(function () {
   $("<div id='fleet-main'></div>")
      .appendTo("#fleet-menu")
      .load("@RenderPage(\"CarTypes.cshtml\")");
});
```

Note that you were mixing quotes too.

Comment: But tell me, the @RenderPage is a function to be executed? Is a javascript function?